# Material UI V4.11.0 - Override Autocomplete nested styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm actually trying to override the input styling for the autocomplete component, I already overrided some of the styles on the theme, but I wasn't able to override the one for the input underline to remove it, on the devtools I found that I have to remove the borderBottom and the content styles but since this is kinda nested nothing that I tried worked:

**Actual behavior**
[image]

**Desired behavior**
[image]

This is what I need

[image]

[image]

This styles are working:

```
MuiAutocomplete: {
      root: {
        paddingLeft: "15px",
        paddingRight: "15px",
      },
      groupLabel: {
        fontWeight: 700,
        color: "black",
        fontSize: 14
      },
      option: {
        paddingTop: "0px",
        paddingBottom: "0px",
        fontSize: 14,
        height: "25px"
      }
    }
```

I tried something like this:

```
    MuiAutocomplete: {
      input: {
        content: "",
        borderBottom: "none"
      },
      inputFocused: {
        content: "",
        borderBottom: "none"
      },
      inputRoot: {
        content: "",
        borderBottom: "none"
      },
      root: {
        paddingLeft: "15px",
        paddingRight: "15px",
      },
      groupLabel: {
        fontWeight: 700,
        color: "black",
        fontSize: 14
      },
      option: {
        paddingTop: "0px",
        paddingBottom: "0px",
        fontSize: 14,
        height: "25px"
      }
    }
```

Also tried using the makeStyles with inputRoot, input and inputFocused with no success:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  inputRoot: {
    "& .MuiInput-underline": {
      content: "",
      borderButton: "none"
    },
    "&:before .MuiInput-underline": {
      content: "",
      borderButton: "none"
    },
    "&.after ..MuiInput-underline": {
      content: "",
      borderButton: "none"
    }
  }
}));
```

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That underline is a pseudo element of the `MuiInput-underline` not the root input. Furthermore, a pseudo element cannot have a child so this `&:before .MuiInput-underline` type of syntax won't work

To solve this issue: just reference the generated root class, its descendant should be `.MuiInput-underline`, with pseudo element `before`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  inputRoot: {
    "& .MuiInput-underline:before": {
      borderBottom: "none"
    }
  }
}));

<Autocomplete
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField classes={{root: classes.inputRoot}} {...params} label="Combo box" />}
/>
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!